# Snowflake : REGEXP replace with uppercase of capture group

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, regexp-replace

I want to replace the very first letter after a comma(,) with uppercase of it in snowflake database. Below given is what I tried, but it did not work.

eg:

```
Apple,ball,cat --> Apple,Ball,Cat
Bulb,LED,tube --> Bulb,LED,Tube
```

```
SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE('Apple,ball,cat',',(\\\w)',UPPER('\\\1'));
```

`,(\\\w)` captures letters after the comma, but `UPPER('\\\1')` does not convert it to uppercase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if you can use functions inside REGEXP_REPLACE at all.

Please use the built-in INITCAP function

```
SELECT INITCAP('Apple,ball,cat', ',');
```

Reference: [INITCAP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/initcap.html#initcap)

Or maybe like this:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(UPPER(LEFT(VALUE, 1)) || SUBSTRING(VALUE, 2, LEN(VALUE)), ',')
  FROM TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE('Apple,ball,cat', ',')) as t(val);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need all letters other than the first letter after comma to remain as it is. INITCAP makes them all lowercase.

Comment: I added another possibility in my answer, I know it's not a beautiful solution, but it works.

Comment: Beat me to it, Michael (+1 btw) !

Answer (score 5):

Not "regex", but if you're interested in a Javascript UDF to do what you need...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fx_replaceInitOnly(
    input varchar)
returns varchar
language javascript
as '
  //logic from https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-capitalize-words-in-javascript/
  var words = INPUT.split(",");

  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      words[i] = words[i][0].toUpperCase() + words[i].substr(1);
  }

  output = words.join(",");
  return output;
';

SELECT 
  'Apple,ball,cat,Bulb,LED,Tube' as str, 
  fx_replaceInitOnly(str) as new,
  case WHEN str <> new THEN 'Changed' ELSE 'Same' END as test;

--STR                           NEW                           TEST
--Apple,ball,cat,Bulb,LED,Tube  Apple,Ball,Cat,Bulb,LED,Tube  Changed
```

Comment: Thank you @Michael Golos for the edit!

Answer (score 4):

Regexp will not help you to upper your chars, so you may combine split_to_table and initcap:

```
SELECT LISTAGG( INITCAP(VALUE) ,','  )
FROM TABLE(SPLIT_TO_TABLE('Apple,ball,cat',','));
```